# Matlab : Removing white colour from the background of an image

Tags: matlab

I have a logo in an an image. The backgroud of the RGB image is all in white. The logo that I'm interested in extracting from the image doesn't have white colour in it.
So I wrote a piece of code in Maltab to remove te white colour and have nothing in the background ans so I set all those white pixels to NaN but they turn to black.
Here's my little script:

```
[filename pathname]=uigetfile('*.*','Choose an image');
file=[pathname filename];
logo=imread(file);
logo=double(logo);
[r g b]=size(logo);
k=1;
for i=1:r
    for j=1:g
            if logo(i,j,k)==255 && logo(i,j,k+1)==255 && logo(i,j,k+2)==255
                logo(i,j,k)=NaN;
                logo(i,j,k+1)=NaN;
                logo(i,j,k+2)=NaN;
            end
        end
end
imshow(logo)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think that NaN values, that have to be displayed, are displayed in black (like a 0,0,0 pixel value). How do you want to display a NaN value (the image continues to be rectangular, not shaped around your extracted logo)

Comment: Yes that's the problem.I want to be left with only the logo without the white background and I don't how to get an image that's shaped around my logo

Comment: It should not be possible because all standard images (in particular in Matlab where are read as matrices) are "rectangular". How do you want to use the extracted logo?